# How do I calculate the number of loonies using the modulus operator in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently, I am supposed to create a program that "The program should have variables for the amount, number of toonies, number of loonies, number of quarters, number of dimes and number of nickels. Assume that the user will always enter an amount to the nearest nickel (no pennies). Display all of the information clearly in the output of the program." I am thinking that I could possibly use the modulus operator to calculate the remainder of coins.

Currently, I have tried to use the float function for the input of the initial value of the program and the int value for the other coins.

```
print ("Hello and Welcome to the Make Change Machine")

Value =float(input("Please enter the amount in dollars and cents:"))
print ("In $",Value,"there are:")
loonie = int(Value/1)
toonie = int(Value/2)
quarters = int((Value-loonie)/0.25)
dimes = int(((Value-loonie)-quarters*0.25)/0.10)
nickel = int(((Value-loonie)- quarters*0.25 - dimes*0.10)/0.05) 
print ("Toonies:",toonie)
print("Loonie:",loonie)
print ("Quarters:",quarters)
print ("Dimes:",dimes)
print ("Nickels:",nickel)
```

I expected the output to be 3, but it ended up being 7

Comment: it might make the problem easier to deal with if you use an `int` of cents instead of a `float` of dollars (or even use a `decimal` of dollars -- floating point shouldn't really be used for currency)

Comment: Do I separate dollars and cents? If so, that would make a lot of sense.